# The negative connotation of the word desert

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the [BBC: ‘Racist’ far-right party Britain First horrifies in BBC documentary](http://www.news.com.au/entertainment/tv/racist-farright-party-britain-first-horrifies-in-bbc-documentary/news-story/4f2bc5a7e1e00f937b11d71f718e1223)

What does the word **desert** mean in the negative form? I am not sure about the intended meaning in the following sentence:

> We Want Our Country Back followed the “patriotic” organisation as it fought to have Islam banned in the UK. In one scene, deputy leader Jayda Fransen says, “Where there are Muslims there is radicalisation”, and in another, members shout, “**Go back to the desert**” from a car.

What do they mean by "Go back to the desert"?

Comment: I've added some context. Please make sure this is where you encountered the sentence. If not, you can roll back the edit.

Comment: It essentially means "go back where you came from", i.e. "we do not want you here"; the desert part arises from the stereotype that all Muslims are Arabs and all Arabs come from the Middle East and all the Middle East is a giant waste of sand dunes, camels, and flying carpets. In short: just run-of-the-mill bigotry (with a healthy dash of ignorance).

Answer (score 1):

The word *desert* is often used metaphorically to describe a deprived environment, as a desert is deprived of water.  Thus from [*Gao Village: A Portrait of Rural Life in Modern China*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pLx66Ql8wyQC&pg=PA162&dq=%22cultural%20desert%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwico4PB9fXKAhUEOD4KHQSDAe84ChDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=%22cultural%20desert%22&f=false) by M C F Gao:

> It is often claimed by the Chinese intelligentsia and some foreign
>   scholars alike that the Cultural Revolution, by burning books and
>   attacking other aspects of traditional Chinese culture, made China
>   into a **cultural desert**.

But in your example, the negative feeling comes from the taunt "Go back," meaning "you don't belong here."  The target was presumably from a desert country, perhaps Saudi Arabia or a country in north Africa.  Had the person addressed been from a country with rain forests, "Go back to the jungle" would have been just as hurtful.

Comment: @Liya I'm from the US, where racism is based on the color line, i.e., the color of a person's skin.  Certainly, telling an African-American to go back to Africa is racist, since most black Americans haver native ancestry going  back farther than most white Americans.  Telling recent Islamic immigrants to back to where they came from (the desert, here) is xenophobic (i.e., based on a fear of strangers), but Islam isn't a race, so the term *racism* is problematic.  It's the same type of ignorant prejudice, though.

Comment: Yet another drive-by downvoter, a curse upon this site.  If you don't have the common courtesy to explain yourself to the answerer, consider that you risk misleading those who seek answers by leaving the impression that correct answers are wrong and leaving wrong answers uncorrected.